# CheckAll/UncheckAll checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a check-box checkall/uncheckall.

HTML

```
<div> Using Check all function </div>
<div id="selectCheckBox">
<input type="checkbox" class="all" onchange="checkAll('selectCheckBox','all','check','true');" />Select All
<input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('selectCheckBox','all','check','false');" />Check Box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('selectCheckBox','all','check','false');" />Check Box 2
<input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('selectCheckBox','all','check','false');" />Check Box 3
<input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll('selectCheckBox','all','check','false');" />Check Box 4
</div>
```

main.js

```
function checkAll(parentId,allClass,checkboxClass,allChecked){
    checkboxAll = $('#'+parentId+' .'+allClass);
    otherCheckBox = $('#'+parentId+' .'+checkboxClass);
    checkedCheckBox = otherCheckBox.filter($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'));
    if(allChecked=='false'){
        if(otherCheckBox.size()==checkedCheckBox.size()){
            checkboxAll.attr('checked',true);
        }else{
            checkboxAll.attr('checked',false);
        }
    }else{
        if(checkboxAll.attr('checked')){
            otherCheckBox.attr('checked',true);
        }else{
            otherCheckBox.attr('checked',false);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine. But get bulky when I have whole lot of checkboxes. I want to do same work by using jQuery rather than putting onchange on each checkbox. I tried different sort of things but couldnot work. I tried following one:

```
$('.check input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e){
    checkAll('selectCheckBox','all','check','true');
});
```

to do same work as onchange event but didnot work. Where do I went wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't the inner quotes be double-quotes in your jq selector: `$('.check input[type="checkbox"]')`?

Comment: sorry that I posted it wrong..

Comment: What is the purpose of passing arguments to checkAll function if their values don't depend on the result of the callback execution? If your function always expect the same values just store them inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need this: You do not need to pass all the arguments and have the inline onchange event attached to it. You can simplify your code.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {
       if(this.className == 'all')
       {
           $('.check').prop('checked', this.checked); //Toggle all checkboxes based on `.all` check box check status
       }
        else
        {
            $('.all').prop('checked', $('.check:checked').length == $('.check').length); // toggle all check box based on whether all others are checked or not.
        }
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hRsR4/)

Comment: @AjayGopalShrestha , You are welcome.  Try avoid using inline event handlers in the markup. Also use prop instead of attr.

Comment: I just wanted to reuse same line of codes for different set of checkboxes with same function. without need of writing same code again and again.

Comment: @AjayGopalShrestha This should work in that case with little tweaks.  if you can just paste your html on a fiddle, i can try help, how it looks with different sets...

Comment: :I do not have my code right now. Just building some basic function for my work. Working on some issues on customized jquery function worked by my seniors. By the way thanks a lot. I learnt something new today.

Comment: @PSL this will break if the class for the *all* checkbox is supplemented with another style class (which is imho not a rare use-case).  Better use `$(this).hasClass("all")` since we already use [tag:jQuery].

Comment: @zsawyer ofcourse yes. But the answer is purely based on OP's markup. He can figure it out. If it doesn't work otherwise. With one class no need to unnecessarily use jquery function.

Comment: @PSL This is like one of the worst regressions to find and debug. I do not see the OP using `HTMLElementObject.className`. You are introducing a potential _hidden_ error source. It is only sensible to assume that the op simplified the markup for SO and expansion is likely. Please reconsider cleaning up your code for the sake of other users who might reuse this good example.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong:

```
.check input[type="checkbox"]
```

Above selects any input of type `checkbox` that has the ancestor with class `.check`. It'll match this:

```
<div class="check">
    <input type="checkbox".../> 
</div>
```

it should be:

```
input.check[type="checkbox"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You closed the string here `$('.check input[type='checkbox']')` instead, you should use double quotes `$('.check input[type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: I posted it wrong on the first place.
I have edited the question again.